# how can I import this file I am getting the error

Tags: python, csv

I am importing csv file for cleaning purpose but pycharm showing me this error

I have tried encoding format but it didn't work

```
import csv
txt1 = ""
txt2 = ""
i = 0
with open('data.csv',encoding='cp1252') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        i += 10
        print(i)
        txt1 = str(row['posts'])
        print(txt1)
        #print(row['type'], row['posts'])
```

My Traceback:

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/mosh/clean.py", line 7, in <module>
>         for row in reader:
>       File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\csv.py",
> line 112, in __next__
>         row = next(self.reader)
>       File `enter code here`"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py",
> line 23, in decode
>     return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>     UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 2409: character maps to <undefined>
>     
>     Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: use utf-8 as the encoding

Comment: try without `encoding='cp1252'`